# How does Dr. Grant know the Tyrannosaurus Rex won't see him?

Tags: jurassic-park

In *Jurassic Park*, in the scene when the *T.rex* escapes from the paddock and attacks the broken down cars, Dr. Grant tells Ian Malcolm not to move, as the *T.rex*'s visual acuity is based on movement.

How do we know this to be true? Was this an invention of Michael Crichton's for the novel, or is this an accepted theory in palaeontology?

[image: The *T.rex* gets loose]

Comment: I was going to suggest that maybe Dr. Grant learned about this when he visited the cloning lab, but googling for info, someone mentioned that Grant brought it up in the scene at the beginning where he scares the kid with the description of Velociraptor, which was before he knew anything about Jurassic Park. If you go to 0:38 in the clip [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2UQv2JUZoU&t=0m38s), you can see he tells the kid "you keep still because you think that maybe his visuality acuity is based on movement, like T. rex, and he'll lose you if you don't move".

Comment: To clarify, this wasn't just in the movie, but book as well. See my comment to RiddlerNewCorners answer

Comment: Its interesting that Peter Jackson leveraged this Jurassic-Park based false "common knowledge" implicitly in the V-Rex chase scene, where Ann Darrow lays still and the V-Rex walks right away missing her completely -- watch it here http://youtu.be/y0UV0U65y4M

Comment: @Shantnu Tiwari - Yes, but it was stupid of the movie to present this as something paleontologists could somehow know based on fossils, rather than presenting it as something scientists noticed about living dinosaurs after cloning them as in the book (see Richard's answer). And even that element of the book is kind of biologically ignorant in its own way if you understand that similar adaptations in different species are likely to be inherited from a common ancestor, see my point in the comments of RiddlerNewComer's answer about the common ancestor of crocs and birds being a dino ancestor too.

Comment: If they can't see things unless they move...they must run into a lot of trees.

Comment: I think in the book it references some animals (deer?) that don't notice some things in their environment as other animals unless they move.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Unfortunately, Dr Grant was wrong, and this theory only comes from Jurassic Park and is not accepted at all in paleontology.

I will use [this article](http://www.iflscience.com/plants-and-animals/could-t-rex-really-only-see-you-if-you-moved) , but there are a lot similar on the web that answers the same question.

The T-Rex has a very developed sense of smell, so the "don't move" theory is already broken by that fact.
Furthermore, he has front-facing eyes, and his binocular range was 55 degrees which is actually greater than that of a hawk.

You can find other crispy details in this article if you want some more infos!

Comment: IIRC there was (at least in the book) a mock-explanation based on Jurassic Park's use of amphibian DNA, as apparently with toads and frogs vision is based largely on detection of movement (not that I actually know anything about frogs, or find that explanation in any way believable).

Comment: Well, T rex in the movie might have frog DNA or ray charles DNA, yet the T-Rex that really existed didn't have such problems :D But yeh the "frog DNA" is quite a good theory for the movie I guess

Comment: The fact that you are using present tense to describe T-Rex's abilities scares me.

Comment: To add: In the 2nd book (The Lost World), Michael Crichton changed the story, so now the T Rex could see non-moving animals. When I read it, I found it quite strange, but no doubt scientists moaned at Crichton, so he fixed it in the 2nd book.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the book was published in 1990 (movie released in 1993) while the cited article is from 2014. Our understanding has likely progressed a long way in 26 years, and just because we know better now doesn't mean it didn't make sense at the time. I concur with both @EikePierstorff and ShantnuTiwari, Dr. Grant specifically cited frogs as his reasoning for movement-based vision, and it was corrected in the sequel (published 1995).

Comment: @aherocalledFrog - I think paleontologists would have seen this as unrealistic in the 1990s too, the main argument against it would probably just be that they already knew that the last common ancestor of birds and crocodilians was also an ancestor of dinosaurs, and both have good vision that isn't limited to motion (see [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=5Cndq9wX2jIC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA8) on crocodile vision).

Comment: (cont.) Googling a little for contemporary commentary, I found [this snippet](http://books.google.com/books?id=wGdOAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=tyrannosaurus+vision) of a paleontology journal from 1995 which apparently includes a review of of the science of Jurassic Park, and which says "The Tyrannosaurus' vision was rather more bird-like than froglike, thus the idea that it could see only moving objects was only necessary to allow the people to escape from sure death".

Comment: @MrLister "We've been observing a T. Rex in our New York laboratory for years, and he can track movement just fine..." kind of scary? :D

Comment: Why did the t-rex not eat him, well it had just eaten a goat and a lawyer, it was full, thus it was more curious than anything. He was right next to the car which the Rex had already toyed with and discovered it was less food and more disgusting, annoying, and possibly painful. Malcom on the other hand was running away and making noise thus he was something new to play with. The moving flares are like your cat with a laser pointer.  At least this was the conclusion of a dozen paleontologists sitting in a theater watching a rerun of the movie prior to the release of the second one.

Answer (score 47):

The movie's [source novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurassic_Park_(novel)) makes it clear that Grant didn't know it beforehand, he **worked it out from observations**, like the good little scientist that he is:

> *The tyrannosaur bellowed in the night air.*
>
> *But **by now Grant was beginning to understand**. The animal couldn't see
>   him, but it suspected he was there, somewhere, and was trying with its
>   bellowing to frighten Grant into some revealing movement. So long as
>   he stood his ground, Grant realized, he was invisible.*

As to *why* the dinos have this peculiar visual impairment, it's described (by Harding) as being something that relates to their amphibian-like physiology:

> *Harding shrugged. “They probably wouldn't react. Dinosaurs have
>   excellent visual acuity, but **they have a basic amphibian visual
>   system: it's attuned to movement.** They don't see unmoving things well
>   at all.”*

Comment: Wow, that's pretty far off.  I wonder why I never noticed that when I read the book?  Maybe it was because of my basic lancelet visual system.

Comment: @RexKerr - I'm wondering if it's because the words were static on the page.

Comment: Can you please animate that with some JavaScript or something?  I'm having trouble understanding you. :)

Comment: @RexKerr Actually, I'm pretty sure I read an admission by Crichton that it was one of his scientific errors in the foreword to The Lost World (and humorously, Ian (resurrected for the sequel - in the original novel, he was presumed dead at the end), mentions that this is obviously absurd). I'm not sure if it was simply a mistake of his, or if the prevalent opinion at the time was that T. Rex indeed *didn't* see static objects. In any case, you probably read the original novel, rather than the "Book of the movie" version, where this was retconned (and Ian didn't die).

Comment: I like to think of it this way: Grant had seen enough to know if he moved, he was dead for sure. May as well try staying still.

Comment: "They don't see unmoving things well at all" ... which makes one wonder how they don't constantly smack into trees (/walls) and trip over rocks and logs (or cars, tables, etc).

Comment: @Glen_b: To this day, *humans* are *much* better at spotting movement than stationary objects. That doesn't mean we're bumping into things either...

Comment: @Glen_b Stationary things appear to move (relative to you) when you're moving.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - alas, except Dr Grant talked about staying still back in Montana at the beginning of the film.